# Change specific words in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web, url-rewriting

I want a .htaccess RewriteRule that makes the server think that "en/blogs" is "blogs/en" in all the urls of the site (notice that it will be in the middle of the URLs). I guess it should be something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)en/blogs(.*) $1blogs/en$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer will work, but it will probably do more than you want.  It will convert

```
www.example.com/en/blogs
```

to

```
www.example.com/blogs/en
```

but it will also convert

```
www.example.com/xen/blogspot
```

to

```
www.example.com/xblogs/enpot
```

In other words, you need to anchor `en` and `blogs`.  `en` will always be preceded by a `/`, and `blogs` will always be followed by a `/` or end-of-line.  So you want

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/en/blogs(/.*|$) $1/blogs/en$2
```